# Regex for words starting and ending with dollar symbol ("$")

Tags: c#, regex

I want to retrieve any word that starts with "`$`" and ends with "`$`" in the data string is

> sdf sdfsdff ffff dd $dsf$ ddd $4rrr2$. $spoif$ $1d4dd$

The data between `$(data)$` doesn't matter.

The result of the data string that is 4 word that start with starts with "`$`" and ends with "`$`".

I do not know what syntax I need in order to create it.

Comment: Is there any code you have come up with? Please share to show what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: And bear in mind that `$` has a special meaning in regular expressions, so you have to escape it.

Comment: This is the code I have come so far. new Regex(@"$(.+?)$"

Comment: You want to retrieve a the word between $word$ but you don't want to retrieve the $data$ ? how is this logical ? From your example what you want to extract.

Comment: @HelloWorld: so, what does not work? [`\$.+?\$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%24.%2b%3f%5c%24&i=sdf+sdfsdff+ffff+dd+%24dsf%24+ddd+%244rrr2%24.+%24spoif%24+%241d4dd%24%22) extracts the 4 "words".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your string may start and end with dollars, you want to make sure you take an ungreedy approach

```
var input = " $dsf$ ddd $4rrr2$. $spoif$ $1d4dd$";
var regexp = new Regex(@"\$(.*?)\$");
foreach (Match match in regexp.Matches(input))
{
     Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Since this answer is accepted, I'd rather you use `\$([^$]*)\$` that matches any characters but `$` inside outermost `$`s.

Answer (score 2):

This regex will get what you want, assuming you want **something** between the dollar symbols:

```
\$\w+\$
```

Or go for this if you will accept `$$` as a valid result:

```
\$\w*\$
```

To break it down, this means:

`\$` the literal character `$`, not the regex symbol for "end of string" which is just `$` without the escape character `\`

`\w` - any word character (excludes white space)

`+` or `*` specify the number of word characters. `+` meaning "1 or more" and `*` meaning zero or more

---

I recommend you have a play around with an online regex tester so you can see what your regex is doing visually in real time, without having to compile and run code. Try:

https://regex101.com/r/jM6lK6/2

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
\$\w*\$
```

The first and last $ have a backslash to escape them as they are special regex characters.

The middle part \w* matches any (word,digit) with zero or more characters

Comment: `\w` does not match whitespace.